# Convert a string to array of array

Tags: php, arrays

I need your help today to convert a string (I'll name it $data) like this one :

```
{"hours":{"2018-06-10 11:00":2,"2018-06-12 07:00":5,"2018-06-12 08:00":4,"2018-06-12 09:00":2,"2018-06-13 09:00":1,"2018-06-13 13:00":1,"2018-06-13 23:00":1,"2018-06-15 13:00":1,"2018-06-15 14:00":1,"2018-06-15 15:00":2,"2018-06-18 06:00":5,"2018-06-18 07:00":9,"2018-06-18 08:00":1,"2018-06-18 09:00":1,"2018-06-18 12:00":2,"2018-06-18 13:00":13},"days":{"2018-06-10 00:00":2,"2018-06-12 00:00":11,"2018-06-13 00:00":3,"2018-06-15 00:00":4,"2018-06-18 00:00":29,"2018-06-18 07:00":2},"weeks":{"2018-06-10 00:00":20,"2018-06-17 00:00":29,"2018-06-18 07:00":2}}
```

to something like this :

- hours (Array)

  - 2018-06-10 11:00 (key) : 2 (value as int)
  - 2018-06-12 7:00 (key) : 5 (value as int)
  - etc...
- days (Array)

  - 2018-06-10 00:00 (key) : 2 (value as int)
  - etc...
- weeks (Array)

  - 2018-06-10 00:00 (key) : 20 (value as int)
  - etc...

I know there's some PHP functions like str_split or explode but I don't really know how to do.
I've tried to make something like :

```
explode('{', $data);
```

or things like that but I don't really know where to start, if I explode with the ":", it will take the ":" in the date too.

If I forgot to put something, just tell me I'll edit the question.

Thanks in advance

Comment: This looks like JSON. See http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

Comment: https://3v4l.org/PEDGK

Comment: This is json. You can use functions to decode json into array and then can manipulate and forumulate the array of your need accordingly.

Comment: Thanks everyone it solved my issue. And sorry, didn't know it was JSON ! Can one of you post it as an answer ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or you can to try this:

```
$data = '{"hours":{"2018-06-10 11:00":2,"2018-06-12 07:00":5,"2018-06-12 08:00":4,"2018-06-12 09:00":2,"2018-06-13 09:00":1,"2018-06-13 13:00":1,"2018-06-13 23:00":1,"2018-06-15 13:00":1,"2018-06-15 14:00":1,"2018-06-15 15:00":2,"2018-06-18 06:00":5,"2018-06-18 07:00":9,"2018-06-18 08:00":1,"2018-06-18 09:00":1,"2018-06-18 12:00":2,"2018-06-18 13:00":13},"days":{"2018-06-10 00:00":2,"2018-06-12 00:00":11,"2018-06-13 00:00":3,"2018-06-15 00:00":4,"2018-06-18 00:00":29,"2018-06-18 07:00":2},"weeks":{"2018-06-10 00:00":20,"2018-06-17 00:00":29,"2018-06-18 07:00":2}}
';

$dados =  json_decode( $data, true );
echo "<pre>";
print_r($dados);
echo "</pre>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Here try this:

```
$json = '{"hours":
                 {"2018-06-10 11:00":2,"2018-06-12 07:00":5,"2018-06-12 08:00":4,"2018-06-12 09:00":2,"2018-06-13 09:00":1,"2018-06-13 13:00":1,"2018-06-13 23:00":1,"2018-06-15 13:00":1,"2018-06-15 14:00":1,"2018-06-15 15:00":2,"2018-06-18 06:00":5,"2018-06-18 07:00":9,"2018-06-18 08:00":1,"2018-06-18 09:00":1,"2018-06-18 12:00":2,"2018-06-18 13:00":13},
                     "days":{"2018-06-10 00:00":2,"2018-06-12 00:00":11,"2018-06-13 00:00":3,"2018-06-15 00:00":4,"2018-06-18 00:00":29,"2018-06-18 07:00":2},"weeks":{"2018-06-10 00:00":20,"2018-06-17 00:00":29,"2018-06-18 07:00":2}
                }';

$toarray = json_decode($json, true);
```

Comment: Can you explain why are you casting it to an array afterwards?

Comment: cause it returns it as a stdClass object

Comment: he said he wanted an array

Comment: In the manual there is a good explanation of what the second argument of json_decode does.

Comment: Please see the second argument of json_decode, which should be used for returning an array instead of an object.

Comment: I think this works very well too

Comment: This will indeed work very well until you're going to use arrays of multiple depth. Casting like this will only work one deep.

Comment: yeah, got it thanks